# Discord selfbot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a selfbot for a server i opperate with some irl friends.
Atm I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to fix my python code.
The bot is supposed to say "lmao" when i say "ayy" and "ayy" when i say "lmao"
Just something fun :)
If possible i would like the selfbot to only respond to me and noone else.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "Token goes here"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "ayy")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ayy lmao")

@b.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "ayy":
        away.b.send_message(message.channel, "lmao")

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FoxMaccloud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\Random\Discord_bot\BetterBakaBot2.py", line 25, in on_message
NameError: name 'away' is not defined
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FoxMaccloud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\Random\Discord_bot\BetterBakaBot2.py", line 25, in on_message
NameError: name 'away' is not defined
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FoxMaccloud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python\Random\Discord_bot\BetterBakaBot2.py", line 24, in on_message
    away.b.send_message(message.channel, "lmao")
NameError: name 'away' is not defined
```

Comment: You don't need both a `Client` and a `Bot`.  (Every `Bot` is also a `Client`). You can get rid of the `client = discord.Client()` line.

Comment: Thank you. Also not sure why, but the part where I say ayy and the bot answers lmao, broke...

Answer (score 2):

I changed line 25 to:

```
await message.channel.send("lmao")
```

Seems to be working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Do This One

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "Token goes here"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "ayy")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ayy lmao")

@b.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    if message.content == "ayy":
        await ctx.send("lmao")

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @user14308313 We are pleased that you answered an old question. You can improve your answer by explaining the things the why your code works and what is the source of your answer (like docs, etc). Well thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "Token goes here"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "ayy")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
print("ayy lmao")

@b.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content == "ayy":
    await ctx.send("lmao")

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

check out [this repository](https://github.com/EinWortspiel/Discord-Selfbot-Base) by [EinWortspiel](https://github.com/EinWortspiel), it's a pretty good selfbot base to get the basics you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32244436)